# Google Guava 15.0 Error with GWT 2.5.1?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, guava

I tried to use [Guave 15.0](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) with GWT 2.5.1 but it fails to compile. I use the compiler parameter -strict. In my module gwt.xml I have:

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
```

I my classpath I added:

```
guava-15.0.jar
guava-gwt-15.0.jar
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Compiling module test.Tttt
   Validating units:
      [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/common/base/super/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java'
         [ERROR] Line 760: SmallCharMatcher cannot be resolved
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

I used a blank gwt project to demonstrate this error. [The project can be found here.](https://github.com/confile/gwt-guava-test.git)

Edit:

When I only include this:

```
guava-gwt-15.0.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
   Validating units:
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.4.0-KEPLER4.3.1/mytest/lib/guava-gwt-15.0.jar!/com/google/common/base/super/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java'
         [ERROR] Line 760: SmallCharMatcher cannot be resolved
```

Edit: Compiled with log level trace:

```
Public resources found in...
   Unexpected entry in classpath; /System/Library/Java/Extensions/libAppleScriptEngine.jnilib is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
   Unexpected entry in classpath; /System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3D.jnilib is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
   Unexpected entry in classpath; /System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3DAudio.jnilib is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
   Unexpected entry in classpath; /System/Library/Java/Extensions/libJ3DUtils.jnilib is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
   Unexpected entry in classpath; /System/Library/Java/Extensions/libmlib_jai.jnilib is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
   Unexpected entry in classpath; /System/Library/Java/Extensions/libQTJNative.jnilib is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
   Unexpected entry in classpath; /usr/lib/java/libjdns_sd.jnilib is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
Translatable source found in...
Persistent unit cache dir set to: /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.4.0-KEPLER4.3.1/tttt/war/../gwt-unitCache
Compiling module test.Tttt
Looking for previously cached Compilation Units in /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.4.0-KEPLER4.3.1/tttt/war/../gwt-unitCache
   Looking for precompiled archives.  To disable, use -Dgwt.usearchives=false
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.5.1/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.5.1/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.5.1/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.5.1/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwtar
   Found 2719 cached/archived units.  Used 2719 / 3026 units from cache.
   Compiling...
      Compilation completed in 3,95 seconds
   Added 3026 units to cache since last cleanup.
   Validating units:
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.4.0-KEPLER4.3.1/tttt/lib/guava-gwt-15.0.jar!/com/google/common/base/super/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java'
         [ERROR] Line 760: SmallCharMatcher cannot be resolved
   Removing invalidated units
Wrote 3026 units to persistent cache.
   Resolving com.google.common.annotations.Beta
      Found type 'com.google.common.annotations.Beta'
         [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
   Resolving com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
      Found type 'com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible'
         [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
   Resolving com.google.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible
      Found type 'com.google.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible'
         [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
   Resolving com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting
      Found type 'com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting'
         [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
   Resolving com.google.common.base.Absent
      Found type 'com.google.common.base.Absent'
         [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
         Found type 'com.google.common.base.Optional'
            [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
            [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.Beta
            Found type 'com.google.common.base.Supplier'
                         com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
   Resolving com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
      Found type 'com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger'
         [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
   Finding entry point classes
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

Comment: CharMatcher is part of guava-15.0.jar. It is not contain in guava-gwt-15.jar. What ever you have done, you can not use CharMatcher on the client side.

Comment: @ElHoss I updated my post still getting an error with only guava-gwt. Any idea?

Comment: Set logLevel to TRACE. That should tell us more about the error.

Comment: @ElHoss I updated my question with log level trace.

Comment: Switch your GWT SDK to 2.5.1. That should solve your problem. I tried your example project and I was able to compile it with GWT 2.5.1. With GWT 2.4.0 I got the same error message.

Comment: Delete the gwt-unit folder. It looks like your are generating your project with an older version of GWT. I can confirm, that your project example can be compiled with GWT 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the gwt-unit folder. It looks like your are generating your project with an older version of GWT. I can confirm, that your project example can be compiled with GWT 2.5.1.