# gwt+guava compilation error:[ERROR] Line 761: MAX_SIZE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: gwt, guava

```
When compiling guava 16.0+gwt 2.6 RC4,I got this error:

[ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/alex/workspace/DSC-Lib/lib/guava-gwt-15.0.jar!/com/google/common/base/super/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java'
[ERROR] Line 760: MAX_SIZE cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Looks a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/q/20253873/116472; BTW, you say you're using Guava 16 but the error references `guava-gwt-15.0.jar`.

Comment: it is a confirmed bug:https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1639

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is Guava version 15.0 included in the GWT SDK. This conflicts with your Guava version 16.0. Either switch to 15.0 as well or play with the classpath order to get it to compile. Now that I think about it switching to Guava version 15.0 is probably the better and more concise approach.

Comment: Thanks,actually,this problem was found in GWT 2.6 RC4+guava 15.0,then I switch to GWT 2.6 RC4+Guava 16.0,found problem remains.Strangely,I can't find directory of /super under ...common/base.Where does it come from?